# How can I get the instance name in Java?

Tags: java

I would like to know if we can get the name of instance name in Java. For example:

```
class A {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Name: " + ????);
  }
}

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] _args) {
    A p = new A();
    A q = new A();

    p.run();
    q.run();
  }
}
```

My expectation result would be:

```
Name: p
Name: q
```

Is it anyway to get this?

Comment: That makes no sense. An object can be assigned to one, many or no variables such as when it is part of a collection. What is its name in each situation? For example `A p = new A();` and then `A q = p;`. What is the object's name? p? q? Answer: variable names don't mean what you think they mean.

Comment: What about an object from an anonymous inner class, such as `button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {...});` what is the name of the ActionListener? Again, the concept has no real meaning.

Comment: I know it's not make sense at all. However the project that I am doing with has some special limitations. Thus I can guarantee that the object that I want to fetch will definitely be assigned once and have explicit name. So I just want to ask if there has some ways to deal with this kind of situations.

Comment: In such a situation, you should post the specifics of your limitations, since without these your question smells like it might very well be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) in disguise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's impossible in Java, not even available through reflection. Your best bet is you have a `String` field where you will store the *name* of the variable and fill this field when creating the object reference.

```
class A {
    private final String name;
    public A(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + this.name);
    }
}
//...
A p = new A("p");
A q = new A("q");
```

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of. Anyway I think I will adopt this solution. Thanks!