# Is there any way to get the instance name in java?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I know that this doesn't make much sense, but I'm trying to create a dynamic method to log the request, for example:

```
   @GetMapping("/my-path")
   public ResponseEntity<Foo> findSomethingBy(Integer bankId, String clientName, FooFilter filter){
       log.info("The method findSomethingBy was called with=" + **dynamicMethotRequest(Arrays.asList(bankId, clientName, filter)**);

       var result = service.findSomethingBy(bankId, clientName, filter);

       log.info("The method findSomethingBy result=" + result);
       return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
   }

   @GetMapping("/my-other-path")
   public ResponseEntity<Foo> findSomethingByAnotherThing(Integer bankId, Integr clientId){
       log.info("The method findSomethingBy was called with=" + **dynamicMethotRequest(Arrays.asList(bankId, clientName)**);

       var result = service.findSomethingByAnotherThing(bankId, clientName, filter);

       log.info("The method findSomethingByAnotherThing result=" + result);
       return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
   }
```

The first expected log from `findSomethingBy` should be:

```
The method findSomethingBy was called with=(bankId=1, clientName=Jack, filter=(age=24, job=dev, working=true, from=Brazil))
```

The first expected log from `findSomethingByAnotherThing` should be:

```
The method findSomethingByAnotherThing was called with=(bankId=1, clientId=1)
```

So how can I do this `dynamicMethotRequest` to get the instance name of each position of array?

This is the way that I'm trying:

```
private String dynamicMethotRequest(List list){
        String result = "";
        var size = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            var element = list.get(i);
            String elemnetName = element.getInstanceName();
            
            if(i == 0){
                result = "(";
            }
            
            result = result + "elemnetName" + "=" + element.toString();
            
            if(i+1 == size){
                result = result + ")";
        }else {
                result = result + ",";
            }
            
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement an interceptor for all requests and get all values from request

creating a interceptor

```java
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor   implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestInterceptor.class);


    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler ) throws Exception{
        doSomethingWithHandleRequest(handler, request);
        return true;
    }

    private void doSomethingWithHandleRequest(Object handler, HttpServletRequest request)throws Exception{
        
        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
            HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) handler;
            LOGGER.info(method.getBeanType().getName()); // class name 
            LOGGER.info(method.getMethod().getName()); // method name
        }

        // request.getHeaderNames() to get all values from headers
        // request.getParameterNames() to get all values from parameters
        // request.getReader() to get body request with HttpServletRequestWrapper() for reading bufferreader
        // and all information on request

    }

 }
```

setting interceptor on configuration

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig  implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor());
    }
    
}
```

so when you call all request will be intercepted on your implementation and get even the result of method return or values on HttpServletResponse

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to retain the information what you called the variable which you passed it into the Array.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907533/how-can-i-get-the-instance-name-in-java) post

If you absolutly have to do this (which you shouldnt have to), you should use a Map.

Comment: In this example that you suggested, always is a class, the mainly problem is when the object is  "primitive". When I use class, I can use @ToString of lombok in it, that already do exactly what I want.
In this case of "primitive" objects, I don't know why i would use map 'cause if I just use `log.inf("The method findSomethingBy was called with=" + Arrays.asList("bankId=" bankId, "clientName=" clientName))" i have the same result of map. This way is how I'm doing today